# SQL server Read scaling on Amazon AWS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

SQL server Read scaling on Amazon AWS

Let me know if this is a good idea.

1. We create a small server that essentially is running all the time.  This is the one to which we would be pushing data. (Master)
2. Create an AMI that acts as a mirror or Replica from the master.  (secondary)
3. Create an Elastic Load balancer  with the primary server running behind it all the time.
4. Create an auto scale group which launches secondary servers when cpu load increases to 50% and kills when cpu drops to 10%
5. On-demand secondary servers are launched, syncs to primary, gets diff and is ready for answering queries.

Questions :

a) Can ELB be used to load balance queries for SQL server ?
b) What kind of replication should I use  transactional / merge ?
c) I am looking into doing this essentially for read scaling ?

Thanks